# EF Core in Update Records with Multiple Child Records with possibility that some are deleted from UI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So I'm using EF core in my app.
I have these sample models which are:

**Product.cs**

```
public class Product{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<ProductDetail> Details {get;set;}
}
```

**ProductDetail.cs**

```
public class ProductDetail {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Location {get;set;}
    public Product Product {get;set;}
    public int ProductId {get;set;}
}
```

Here's my sample data from UI JSON format

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Updated Product Name",
    "details": [
         { "id": 1, "productId": 1, "location": "Updated location 1" },
         { "id": 2, "productId": 1, "location": "Updated location 2" }
    ]
}
```

And this is my update method. Which is working fine if I update the data from the details.

```
...
context.Products.Update(products)
```

But my problem is, what if I deleted a data like this:

Here's my sample data from UI JSON format

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Updated Product Name",
    "details": [
         { "id": 1, "productId": 1, "location": "Updated location 1" }
    ]
}
```

So far, what I created is to delete all the records then re-create new ones but it seems not a good practice though since I only want to remove what is not existing from the ui and just update the other data in the details as part of the `.Update` EF.

**EDIT :**
Additionally, there's mapper method before going to the `UpdateMethod`. Here it is:

```
private Product SaveMapper(ProductDto productDto)
{
    foreach (var detail in productDto.ProductDetails) { 
        detail.Product = null; // I put null here because it has string value name from the ui. Example, the actual product name.
    }

    return mapper.Map<Product>(productDto);
}
```

And I call this in my update

```
public async bool UpdateProductService(ProductDto productDto){
    return await repo.Update(SaveMapper(productDto));
}
```

Any help on how can do this properly?

Comment: JSON has nothing to do with ORMs and EF core. Post the *relevant* code.  `context.Products.Update(products)` alone won't make any updates, it marks an object as modified. All pending changes are persisted when you call `SaveChanges`. If you want to modify lots of objects, load or attach all of them, modify them, then call `SaveChanges` just once

Comment: BTW this is very well documented and shown in all courses and tutorials, especially ASP.NET Core tutorials in the docs. [DbSet.Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-5.0) explains that `Begins tracking the given entity and entries reachable from the given entity using the Modified state by default, ... Generally, no database interaction will be performed until SaveChanges() is called`.

Comment: [DbSet.UpdateRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.updaterange?view=efcore-5.0) does the same for multiple entities at once

Comment: Could you please also share the `repo.Update()` method?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following approach -

```cs
public void MyProductUpDateMethod(Product product)
{
    // fetch the existing entity with child list
    var dbProduct = context.Products.Include(p => p.Details)
                    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == product.Id);
    
    // set the properties
    dbProduct.Name = product.Name;
    dbProduct.Details = product.Details;
    
    // save changes
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This should work if you added, removed or modified any child entity.

Comment: I tried it, it works on edit and add new. but after I delete one, it doesn't delete on the backend.

Comment: I tried putting the `AsNoTracking` but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: @hikhyper update works. You don't need to do anything special or any kind of "encoding" whatever that may mean. `AsNoTracking()` is only going to *cause* problems. Don't try things at random. If you have lots of objects to update, load them all with a single query, modify them then make a single call to `SaveChanges`

Comment: @hikhyper 1) I didn't understand what you meant by "_encode them_". 2) The approach shown should work for delete as well. If you already had three `ProductDetail` for this `Product` in database, and then you receive a product data from client side containing only two product detail data, then the one absent in the request will be deleted. That's how it works for me. 3) You should not use `AsNoTracking` in this case, because the entities needs to be tracked until `SaveChanges` is called.

Comment: I'm having an error that says like `The instance of entity type 'ProductDetail' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ProductDetailId'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values`

Comment: @hikhyper When exactly is this occurring?

Comment: After the `context.SaveChanges();` then it goes to my catch exception.

Comment: I don't have any other queries before that and I already made my code synchronous method similar to your example, I also removed the `AsNoTracking` but still, it throws this cannot be tracked error. @atiyar

Comment: @hikhyper Could you add that information as an `EDIT` section in your post, (with what `Product` and `ProductDetail` list you were trying to update? Also, what database server are you using?

Comment: I'm using MSSQL Server for this @atiyar

Comment: @hikhyper I tried the code with SQL Server, and it works. That means you are dong something differently, which is not mentioned in the post. Edit the post and add all the info I mentioned in the comment above. Also, the method you are using for the operation, the complete method.

Comment: Basically, it looks similar to your example. Nothing fancy, just from controller then to update service

Comment: @hikhyper If you can edit/update the post, may be I will spend some more time to take another look.

Comment: I forgot to mention the mapper, but no queries going on there as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229492/discussion-between-hik-hyper-and-atiyar).